# iOS 9 App Transport Security

Tags: admob, ios9, xcode7, app-transport-security

I read you're supposed to add App Transport Security in info.plist if you get the following message in debug area:

**“App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app’s Info.plist file.”**

I never received this message in Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9. I'm using AdMob as well and it states that ATS may affect your ads being shown if ATS is ON. However, I have no issue with AdMob or iAd ads showing whether test ads or live ads and I never receive the ATS message in debug area.

I also read if you do put the ATS code into info.plist, Apple may reject your app if they find you had no good reason to do so.

So, how do I know if I NEED to implement ATS code in info.plist or not?

Comment: When you call an http request the app gives the App Transport Security warning. When you call an httpS request the app doesn't. I think AdMob is using https request so you don't need to worry. ;)

Comment: I use iAd, AdMob and Chartboost. What about iAd and Chartboost? I have an iOS game and I used SLComposeViewController to implement Twitter/facebook share button. In Twitter share button I have an http link that use can share onto their twitter page. Do I need to add this ATS thing into info plist ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically as far as i understood it ATS means you can no longer use http in any call to outbound urls as they will be blocked. you need to implement this change into your plist only if you plan on using http calls.

In order to exclude communications from the ATS limitation you must specify the domain name in the info.plist.

Unless one of the libraries you use has specific urls that you need to allow if you have no specific servers you contact through un-secure connections (not https) than you don't have to do anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by using http calls? My app is an iOS game. I have a Facebook/ Twitter share button implemented via SLComposeViewController. when you click on Twitter button for example, the share message pops up and and in there is an http link to my app store page that the use can share onto their twitter page. 

Does this ATS thing apply to me too? Do I need to add it in info.plist?

Comment: if you are not aware of any HTTP calls to external apis you do, there is proably no need to enable it. also in order to enable it you need to specify excluded domains. i'll update my answer to reflect that.